# Combobox KeyDown event handler firing multiple times

Tags: vb.net, combobox, keydown

In VB.NET, I have a Combobox on a WinForm form.  The form allows the user to type in a query to be searched.  When the user hits the Enter key, a query is performed against the database and the results are returned as a DataTable.  The DataTable is then bound to the Combobox and the user can select the option that they are looking for.

For the most part, this is working great.  However, we've discovered that the code is executing multiple times.  If I write my query out and hit the Enter key ONCE, I can step through the code TWO or THREE times.  I don't want to send the same query to the database multiple times if I do not have to.  Any ideas or suggestions why the code would be executing multiple times?

Here is the code in question.  The Combobox and Function names have been changed to protect the innocent.  :)

```
Private Sub cbx_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cbx.KeyDown

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        PerformSearch()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have another Event Handler defined somewhere else? Something like AddHandler cbx.KeyDown, AddressOf Me.cbx_KeyDown

Comment: I had the same problem with the keydown event for a form.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Except since it's a form event the focus solution doesn't work. :-(

Comment: So instead I just trap the last key pressed and if it's the same I exit the sub.  If it's the key I'm trapping for I clear it out of my comparison buffer so I don't loose a purposeful double press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, adding cbx.Focus() after the search has been performed fixed the problem.  Here is the solution.

```
Private Sub cbx_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cbx.KeyDown

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        PerformSearch()
        cbx.Focus()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to believe.  It can't get the KeyDown event if it doesn't have the focus.  Watch out for non-typing keys like Shift, Control, Alt.